# Using Greek font for English characters?

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

http://www.oliviapalermo.com/

talking about the heading in the banner. the font being used is GFS didot
which as far as I can tell is a Greek letter font?

what am I missing?

Comment: where exactly did the font not register?!!! we cannot sift through all your lines of code

Comment: What is the question? I can see GFS Didot Regular used in there, so that's not the problem. Is the page supposed to be displayed in Greek? Are you under the impression that a Greek font can't contain ASCII glyphs?

Comment: Yes I was under that impression. I guess it can contain ASCII.. It was not available in my googlefont library either

Comment: The [Google Fonts GFS Didot](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/GFS+Didot) page says "The typeface is accompanied by a matching latin alphabet based on Hermann Zapf’s Palatino."...